# Sending data to a Linux tap interface without using sudo

Tags: linux, networking, jenkins

I'm trying to set-up unit tests for my networking scripts. As the unit tests are run by a non-root user ("jenkins", typically), I want to be able to set-up an network interface that can be used by jenkins just to test the packets that are being sent from my networking scripts. The program I'm testing uses the network interface in "promiscuous" mode and, ultimately, is run under the root user as a Linux service. However, I want the functionality unit tested without requiring root login or interactive input - The jenkins "user" is not an interactive user on the system.

I can set-up a tap interface (CentOS 7.x) in the following manner:

```
sudo ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user jenkins
sudo ifconfig tap0 promisc up
```

This brings up an interface, which I can see using `ifconfig`, but it is not "RUNNING".

I can send data to it by running my program using `sudo XXXX`, so my program is working as expected. However, if I run the program through the jenkins account, the packets are not going through - I can temporarily switch the jenkins user account to be "interactive" to try this. I'm using Wireshark to view the throughput on this interface.

I've tried this using my own user account, and other accounts, but only the root account works.

I feel there is some command-line invocation I can use to allow a non-root user to utilize a (private, user-owned) network interface, but I can find nothing.

I *could* possibly work out a system using `sudo` and/or suid (`chmod 4755 XXX`) permissions that would allow the unit tests to run with root privileges, but it seems that I should be able to run automated tests without having to go through this somewhat tortuous process.

Does anybody know how I can utilize a tap interface from a user account?

Note: Ultimately, my program uses `libpcap`'s `pcap_inject` to inject a packet into the interface. If anyone knows of a different programmatic solution, that is another way of tackling this problem.

Also, I can inject packets as a non-root user onto my real network interface and that works, but it's somewhat dangerous to be letting my packets (which could be erroneous) loose onto the real network. It seem incongruous that a user can utilize a real interface, but not utilize a "tap" interface for testing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am trying to develop a program and run unit tests for that program, but I appreciate it may *specifically* be more relevant to administration tasks. Is there a way I could transfer the question to one of those boards? I understand they're run by the same system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the libpcap library does not allow access to a tap interface set-up in this way.

To resolve this, I needed to write the C/C++ code in the system to write directly to the network interface's file descriptor using code such as this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

...

struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI;
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "tap0", IFNAMSIZ);
int fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR);
int err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void*) &ifr);

...

int rc = write(fd, packetData, length);
```

Ultimately, this was resolved with a programmatic solution. I really don't think there is an sys-admin solution to this to continue using the libpcap library.

Note: I try to open the tap device this way first, before going on to use libpcap (which is useful for other situations). This is because libpcap can fail silently when trying the same and returns no errors, but simply does not work.